# how to kill process passwd from a second terminal. Root process cannot be killed?

Tags: command-line, root, process, kill, ps

I have my one terminal running the passwd command, without entering new password.
then with a second terminal I need to kill the process passwd, however as it is a root process I don't know how to kill it.

sudo kill 1234 doesn't work...

could you please help me?
thanks

Comment: can use `killall -9 passwd` .... all signal is listed in `man 7 signal`

Comment: hi, thanks. if i run killall -9 passwd, it comes up with "no process found".

Comment: sudo killall -9 passwd